# Proper way to return a List<String^> to a Vector<std::string> in Extern "C"?

Tags: c#, c++, command-line-interface

I'm communicating between CLI and I need to return back a vector of strings from my C function. I have not done much cli between c++/c# so please tell me if there is a better way to accomplish this.

```
//Plugin.cpp
void PluginMain(){
  ServiceClientHook();
}

//Plugin.h;
extern "C" {
  vector<std::string> ServiceClientHook();
}

//ServiceClientHook.h
#include "Plugin.h"

//ServiceClientHook.cpp
string ServiceClientHook()
{
    return "Foobar";
}
```

How do I handle ServiceClientHook()? I should add that I am using non cli on my Plugin and cli on my ServiceClientHook

Currently when I try and return a vector from 'Plugin.h': *C linkage function cannot return C++ class 'std::vector>'*

Comment: `extern "C"` is used for C++ functions accessed through p/invoke, not and not needed when using C++/CLI.  Please (edit the question) show the parts of the system, what language each is using, so we can figure out the best way to transfer a bunch of strings in your particular scenario.

Comment: @BenVoigt **Edited**, Unfortunately  I don't know how I to pass the List of strings so I am just passing back a String. 'It's not working in this case seeing how I am accepting a vector of std strings' but you get the idea.

Comment: Are Plugin.cpp and ServiceClientHook.cpp in the same project?  Or is one in a DLL that the other one calls?  I know all about many types of strings and vectors and lists and how to pass them between every technology you named in your question... but I don't know the structure of your project.  You have a tag for [tag:c#] but none of the code is C#.  You have mentioned `List<String^>` in your title (which should be `List<String^>^`) and it doesn't appear in your code.  You have a tag [tag:command-line-interface] which is probably wrong.  And haven't given any reason to be using `extern "C"`

Comment: Help me help you, by saying what modules (DLL or EXE) exist, what function needs to be in each one, what language is used in each one, where the data comes from and where it needs to go.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I am creating a DLL, I am calling a operational contract between 2 different projects with my *ServiceClientHook* (This gets a List<String^>^) then I am trying to pass that to my *Plugin* as any sort of iiterable object. These two files [ServiceClientHook, Plugin] the same project. While I have posted this question I have started passing back a list<string>* but its not ideal. 

**Simple answer**: I receive a List<String^>^ in my ServiceClient and I want to pass it to my Plugin from a extern "C". 

Also I am using a List<String^>^ I just omitted the last carrot.

Comment: If Extern C is not the correct way to do this please tell me, as I am not too familiar with what is best. I have to use CLI because the program the plugin runs on will not work with unmanaged code.

Comment: So `ServiceClientHook()` is a C++ function being called from a C++/CLI function in the same project?  Or it is being called from the Host Application (outside the plugin)?  In the first case, you don't need `extern "C"`, it will only get in your way.  In the second case, you need to match the exact return type that the Host Application expects its plugins to return.

Comment: It is really hard to understand the question even with the clarification. If you want to convert ˋList<String ^> ^` to ˋstd::vector<std::string>`, then use C++/CLI and write code to do the conversion. Usually, however, you don't use extern C for such types...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have two functions in the same C++/CLI DLL project:

- `PluginMain` -- talks to an unmanaged EXE, maybe C++, maybe not
- `ServiceClientHook` -- talks to a C# DLL

You don't need to do anything special at all to have these talk to each other.  Get rid of the `extern "C"` on `ServiceClientHook()` and it will just work.  Even though `ServiceClientHook()` is in a file using `/clr` and `PluginMain` is plain C++.

Now, `PluginMain` may need to have `extern "C"` and `__declspec(dllexport)` to help the EXE find it.  But those requirements don't apply to the functions it uses.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I thought I needed extern to communicate with unmanaged / managed.

Comment: @i73: Nope, the C++/CLI compiler layer for managed/unmanaged interop is called "It Just Works" and usually it does.  `extern "C"` is most often used for calls across DLL boundaries, especially if different compiler versions (and maybe different programming languages) are used -- or might be different in the future when one gets recompiled using the latest and greatest and the other is left alone.